# How to apply the torch.inverse() function of PyTorch to every sample in the batch?

Tags: python, pytorch

This may seem like a basic question, but I am unable to work it through.

In the forward pass of my neural network, I have an output tensor of shape 8x3x3, where 8 is my batch size. We can assume each 3x3 tensor to be a non-singular matrix. I need to find the inverse of these matrices.
The PyTorch [inverse()](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.inverse) function only works on square matrices. Since I now have 8x3x3, how do I apply this function to every matrix in the batch in a differentiable manner?

If I iterate through the samples and append the inverses to a python list, which I then convert to a PyTorch tensor, should it be a problem during backprop? (I am asking since converting PyTorch tensors to numpy to perform some operations and then back to a tensor won't compute gradients during backprop for such operations)

I also get the following error when I try to do something like that.

```
a = torch.arange(0,8).view(-1,2,2)
b = [m.inverse() for m in a]
c = torch.FloatTensor(b)
```

> TypeError: 'torch.FloatTensor' object does not support indexing

Answer (score 11):

**EDIT:**

**As of Pytorch version 1.0, `torch.inverse` now supports batches of tensors. See [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.inverse). So you can simply use the built-in function `torch.inverse`**

OLD ANSWER

There are plans to implement batched inverse soon. For discussion, see for example [issue 7500](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/7500) or [issue 9102](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/9102). However, as of the time of writing, the current stable version (0.4.1), no batch inverse operation is available.

Having said that, recently batch support for `torch.gesv` was added. This can be (ab)used to define your own batched inverse operation along the following lines:

```
def b_inv(b_mat):
    eye = b_mat.new_ones(b_mat.size(-1)).diag().expand_as(b_mat)
    b_inv, _ = torch.gesv(eye, b_mat)
    return b_inv
```

I found that this gives good speed-ups over a for loop when running on GPU.

Comment: For the time being this seems like the best bet. Thanks.

Comment: What is the alternative for torch.gesv? Seems like it is deprecated.

Comment: `torch.gesv` has been replaced with [`torch.solve`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.solve) in pytorch-1.2.0 ([source](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/22841))

Answer (score 1):

You could split the tensor using `torch.functional.unbind()`, apply inverse to every element of the result, and then stack back:

```
a = torch.arange(0,8).view(-1,2,2)
b = [t.inverse() for t in torch.functional.unbind(a)]
c = torch.functional.stack(b)
```

Comment: This seems very very slow!

Comment: In torch 1.1 `unbind` has vanished. `torch.functional.split` can be used instead.